# Read data from firebase and display in chat using Node Js

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I am new to the Firebase realtime database and Google Dialogflow. I have gone through the documents and working on through. I am reading the data from database and I want to display it in my chat. I am able to see the data in the logs but unable to display in the chat conversation. If I check the logs I am able to see the success or failed result but unable to view in the chat conversation.

This is the code below:

```
var childData = "";    
var message = '';    
var query = '';
var key = '';

function wheretogo(agent) {    
    //taking country name as input from user    
    var country = request.body.queryResult.parameters.country;    
    //reference country from the database    
    query = admin.database().ref("country").orderByKey();    
    query.once("value")    
        .then(function(snapshot) {    
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {    
                key = childSnapshot.key;    
                childData = childSnapshot.val();    
                //matching the input from user and the country name(key) from database    
                if (country === key) {    
                    console.log("sucess");    
                    message = 'Thats nice ! You are travelling to ' + key;    
                    agent.add(message);    
                }
                 else 
                 {
                   console.log("failed");
                 }    
                });
             });
           }
```

I expect the output 'Thats nice ! You are travelling to ' with country name in my chat conversation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Dialogflow library expects you to return a Promise if you're doing any asynchronous calls. Since you're doing an async call (the `query.once()` call), you must return a Promise. Otherwise the handler dispatcher won't wait for the reply to come from the database before it tries to send a reply to the user.

You don't show all of your code, but in your case it looks fairly straightforward. Since `query.once()` returns a Promise, you can return this Promise. Something like this change

```
 return query.once("value")
```

might be all that is necessary.

Comment: Glad it works! If an answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.

Comment: Glad to up vote the answer @Prisoner but i have less reputation don't mind!!

Comment: You can always accept an answer to a question you posted.

Comment: query = admin.database().ref('country/'+country+'/mobileEntitlement/').orderByKey();

https://traveldesk.firebaseio.com/country/Australia/mobileEntitlement(here i have country named australia in the database and it is hitting that link correctly)
But the problem is i dont have country japan in my database but still it is hitting the below link which is not present in the database
https://traveldesk.firebaseio.com/country/japan/mobileEntitlement(here it has to throw error because in the link path japan is not present still it is hitting the database)

Comment: Please don't post code in a comment - it is very difficult to understand. It is also not clear if this is really the same question as before, or if this is a new question. If it is a new question, please post it as a new question. If it is an update of this question, please update the question to clarify.